# How to Format fb.created_time

Tags: javascript, facebook, format

I am new to javascript and I used the tutorial found here: http://www.prettyklicks.com/blog/making-a-facebook-feed-using-the-graph-api-json-and-jquery/291/ but I am having trouble formatting the date given by facebook. My website is http://moussesalon.com/homePage.htm and my code is as follows:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.fbstatus = function(options) {

        set = jQuery.extend({
            username: 'Removed for privacy',
            token: 'Removed for privacy',
            loading_text: null
        }, options);

        function fbstatus_link(text){
            return text.replace(/(href="|<a.*?>)?[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+/g, function($0, $1) {
              return $1 ? $0 : $0.link($0);
            });
        }


        //Set Url of JSON data from the facebook graph api. make sure callback is set with a '?' to overcome the cross domain problems with JSON
        var url = "Removed for privacy";

        $(this).each(function(i, widget){
            var loading = $('<p class="loading">'+set.loading_text+'</p>');
            var theObject = $(this);
                if (set.loading_text) $(widget).append(loading);


            //Use jQuery getJSON method to fetch the data from the url and then create our unordered list with the relevant data.
            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                var html = "<ul>";

                    //loop through and within data array's retrieve the message variable.
                    $.each(json.data,function(i,fb){

                        if (fb.message) {
                            html += "<li>" + fbstatus_link(fb.message) + "<br>" + fb.created_time + "</li>" + "<br>";
                        }

                    });
                html += "</ul>";


                //A little animation once fetched
                theObject.animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){

                        theObject.html(html);

                });

                theObject.animate({opacity:1}, 500);

            });

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the main [Graph API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under 'Dates' you can ask the API to return results in any date format you want - why not just get Facebook to return the dates in your preferred format?

Excerpt from docs:

> All date fields are returned as ISO-8601 formatted strings. You can optionally override the date format by specifying a "date_format"
>   query parameter. The accepted format strings are identical to those
>   accepted by the php date function. For example,
>   https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?date_format=U returns the
>   Platform page's feed, with unixtime-formatted dates.

Comment: I can't figure out how to integrate this into my existing code. I am a super noob with javascript.

Comment: add date_format=X to your API call, where X represents the date format you're expecting - you can see possible options here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - it uses the same placeholder values as the Graph API

Comment: Could you copy my API call and insert the code. I'm not sure where to put it because I'm not sure what an API call is...Sorry Man.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the javascript function

```
string.substring(from, to);
```

This will allow you to specify the start character (0 for the start of the string) to the last character you want (length - 5)

```
fb.created_time.substring(0,(fb.created_time.length-5));
```

Comment: I found this useful. I just cut off everything past the date. I just hope that in the 1 digit days that it doesn't remove a digit from the date. I subtracted 11 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this...

```
//graph API call
https://graph.facebook.com/YOURNAME?fields=YOURFIELDSHERE&date_format=F j, Y, g:i a&access_token=ACCESSTOKENHERE"
```

The results will be the date of the post such as; April 13, 2017, 4:40 pm